# How to generate insight from code stored in BitBucket GIT repo

Tags: git, statistics, bitbucket, code-statistics

There are over 40k repositories in our company's bitbucket repository... and there are numerous questions which are super tricky to answer due to the size of the organization.

One of such questions is.

How many projects/components are implemented as spring.boot apps.

Simple query 
`ext:xml org.springframework.boot` returns over 1.5k result.

I'm looking for an idea / advice how to retrieve information which can help to identify which out of those files belong to a project which is still "alive".

E.g. I would like to produce a table with following columns

| project name  | repository name | file path | last commit to the repository (date/time) |

any ideas how to approach such topic ?

Comment: Bitbucket Server or Bitbucket Cloud?

Comment: Bitbucket server